# Is there a way to add a prefix/suffix to all similar files in subfolders of a directory?

Tags: r, path, file-rename, prefix

I have a directory with a couple of subfolders I will give an example:

```
Fruit-> Red->Berries->strawberry.jpg  
Fruit-> Red->Berries->raspberry.jpg
```

I would like to include the subfolder names into my file names ex:

```
From: strawberry.jpg  
To: Fruit_Red_strawberry.jpg
```

But also I would like to be able to add a prefix to all files that have a .JPG ending. So for example:

```
Fruit_Red_strawberry.jpg  
Fruit_Red_raspberry.jpg
```

Add a prefix of `YES_` so that it's:

```
YES_Fruit_Red_strawberry.jpg  
YES_Fruit_Red_raspberry.jpg
```

Comment: What happened to "Berries" folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# use list.files with full paths
#x <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)

#example files with full paths for testing
x <- c("Fruit/Red/Berries/strawberry.jpg",
       "Fruit/Red/Berries/raspberry.jpg", 
       "Fruit/Red/Berries/test.txt")

#replace / with _
newNames <- gsub("/", "_", x, fixed = TRUE)

#prefix YES
newNames <- ifelse(tools::file_ext(x) == "jpg",
                   paste0("YES_", newNames), newNames)

#prefix with folder
newNames <- paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(x), newNames, sep = "/")

newNames
# [1] "Fruit/Red/Berries/strawberry/YES_Fruit_Red_Berries_strawberry.jpg"
# [2] "Fruit/Red/Berries/raspberry/YES_Fruit_Red_Berries_raspberry.jpg"  
# [3] "Fruit/Red/Berries/test/Fruit_Red_Berries_test.txt" 

#then rename old with new names
#file.rename(x, newNames)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes sorry about the berries folder!  this does what I need! One more quick question if it is okay with you: can the prefix of the file path/ subfolders be arranged in different order? Or would that require an entirely different process ?

Comment: @JimboBiggly edit your question with expected output. In any case this answer should be enough to manipulate the file names to your needs.